# Hosting Microsoft Edge via WebView2Loader.dll with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-edge, chromium, webview2

The company I work for has developed some Excel workbooks with quite comprehensive VBA applications that uses WebBrowser (IE) embedded into a UserForm. Now when IE is end of it's life cycle there's a  need to think about different approach. Edge would be the way to go but because these workbooks are also distributed to external parties Selenium driver is out of scope.

I saw that they have managed to utilize WebView2Loader.dll in AutoHotkey scripts here https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=81354 and here https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=79868

Would there be a way to do something similar with VBA? Basically it's COM wrapper around that WebView2 DLL.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: The retirement is just for IE11 desktop application, IE platform (MSHTML/Trident) including WebOC will still be supported. For more information, you can refer to [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549). The [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#supported-platforms) doesn't provide samples to use WebView2 in VBA, if you really need to do this, you can refer to [this thread](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?889202-VB6-WebView2-Binding-(Edge-Chromium)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently WebBrowser control is used for user interaction with the application and that's the only way to properly embed and render web-pages to userforms for the users (by using WebBrowser / IE control). Installing / distributing additional libraries like that RC6 is out of question. But, I found another solution which seems to work.  For  who is interested, here is the link: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5307593/Automate-Chrome-Edge-using-VBA. Before today I were not aware of CDP protocol: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/ which does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's API to communicate with Chromium / EDGE from VBA without need to install any external libraries. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5307593/Automate-Chrome-Edge-using-VBA

It utilizes CDP (Chrome DevTools Protocol): https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/